# Issues with importing Arabic CSV content coming out as?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am importing and excel file(.csv) which contains arabic characters and English. When I extracting the content using 'file_get_contents', Everything works great.

But the arabic string 'يض' comes out as ????

Comment: is it being served as the proper UTF encoding?

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` is known to often misinterpret UTF8.

Can you try something like this:

```
function file_get_contents_utf8($fn) {
    $content = file_get_contents($fn);
    return mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8',
        mb_detect_encoding($content, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));
}
```

Comment: Yes My Bad. It was not serving as UTF-8.